# Does Srivaishnavite theology explain why limited celestial beings like Indra don't perform Sharanagati to Vishnu and get liberated?

Tags: vishnu, sharanagati

As far as I know, Indra,Brahma et al are never depicted as performing Sharanagati to Vishnu and becoming muktatamas - something that is available to ordinary human Visnu-devotees.

They are often depicted as praising Vishnu as Brahman - but I don't recall that they are said to have become muktatmas.

Comment: Instead many of devas are depicted selfish